# Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, php-7.4

I'm getting this error on multiple occasion in a script (invoiceplane) I have been using for a few years now but which hasn't been maintained unfortunately by its creators:

```
Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

My server has been upgrade to PHP 7.4 and I'm looking for a way to fix the issues and maintain the script myself since I'm very happy with it.

This is what's on the line that gives the error:

```
$len = $cOTLdata['char_data'] === null ? 0 : count($cOTLdata['char_data']);
```

$cOTLdata is passed to the function:

```
public function trimOTLdata(&$cOTLdata, $Left = true, $Right = true)
{
    $len = $cOTLdata['char_data'] === null ? 0 : count($cOTLdata['char_data']);
    $nLeft = 0;
    $nRight = 0;
    //etc
```

It's included in [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf) btw, but simply overwriting the files from the github repository did not fix the errors.

Comment: Change it to 
`$len = count($cOTLdata['char_data'] ?? []);`

Comment: I had this same crash; I fixed it by moving to mpdf8 (I think on the version number)

Comment: Unfortunately newer PHP versions are more strict on such declarations

Answer (score 163, accepted):

This happens because `$cOTLdata` is null. Previous versions of PHP may have been less strict on such mistakes and silently swallowed the error / notice while 7.4 does not do this anymore.

To check whether `$cOTLdata` is null use [is_null()](https://www.php.net/is_null):

```
is_null($cOTLdata)
```

Which means the line should look something like this:

```
$len = is_null($cOTLdata) ? 0 : count($cOTLdata['char_data']);
```

However, in case both `$cOTLdata` and `$cOTLdata['char_data']` could not exist, you can use `isset()` for both at once:

```
$len = !isset($cOTLdata['char_data']) ? 0 : count($cOTLdata['char_data']);
```

Comment: Seems logical, slapping myself thinking I could of thought of this myself. Blaming last night, it was late :) Will be a hell of a job to change all these occurrences, but beats moving to another system. I will test it with one occurrence first. Thanks.

Comment: i have this error i dont understand your explanation

Comment: @kipruto If you do not find an answer satisfactory you can always ask a new question. However please note that even this was marked as a duplicate since this is a fairly common question, so reading other answers might be a good first step.

Comment: @kipruto changing to php7.2 fixes this error

Comment: I would strongly advise against using an old PHP version that is [not supported anymore](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) like it is the case for 7.2.

Comment: No, not always.  when doing a dump, I see the index DOES exist, yet PHP 7.1 keeps insisting that it does not.

Comment: For me, i was running a project which built on symfony 2.7 and it was a cache issue, I removed the cache and the error was gone.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If the index doesn't exist you get "Undefined index". This error means that the variable is null.

Comment: @Barmar I was able to replicate the same error by doing this: `$arr = array(0 => array('name' => 'Ang'), 1 => array('name' => 'Bel')); print_r( $arr[3]['name']) ;` Since I'm accessing (`'name'`) from something that does not exists(`$arr[3]`) , the error is Trying to access array offset on value of type null... so this answer is correct.

Comment: @Barmar is correct as you can easily test: https://3v4l.org/Yoh6Q / https://3v4l.org/lu3fj

Comment: @Tgr there is "edit" button under the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you are trying to use a null (or a non-existent value) as array. Which definitely means that *logic* of your program is broken.

First of all you must understand that every error message PHP generates is meant to help you, and to make your code cleaner and less error-prone. When your code contains a bug, your best bet is to *fix* it, not to *brush it off*. Sadly, the accepted answer only elaborates on the latter. But you should really consider doing the former.

Every error message helps you to find a bug in the code. It means that errors shouldn't be intentional or "habitual". This way you won't have to silence them, and every error would mean that your code indeed encountered a bug.

It just makes no sense to access a null or a non-existent variable as though it's array. You can only use array offset on arrays, [special type of objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and (using only numeric indices) [on strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr). But if you get a null value where array is expected, it means that the data flow in your program is broken. And you need to fix it.

Just like in your case. Definitely, `$cOTLdata` contains `null` while your code expects it to be an array. Therefore, **you need to fix the code that assigns value to `$cOTLdata.`**

So, as a rule, just make sure that every function that should return an array, returns an array, or any variable that should contain an array, contains an array. And you won't see this error message again. Unless, due to some mistake, your code will return a non-array value unexpectedly. And this error message *will* help you to pinpoint this problem.

When things are not under your control, like, you need to get an array from an outside variable, do a *validation* first. For example, in case you are expecting an array from a form, that is obligatory, validate it and return an error, like

```
if (!isset($_POST['options']) || !is_array($_POST['options'])) {
   // inform the user ad stop execution
} else {
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
// now you can safely use count() on $options
```

In case the array is optional, you may initialize it as empty array:

```
if (!isset($_POST['options'])) {
    $options = [];
} elseif (!is_array($_POST['options'])
   // inform the user ad stop execution
} else {
    $options = $_POST['options'];
}
// now you can safely use count() on $options
```

And only as a last resort you may silence this error, using `is_null()` or `isset()`

But you shouldn't just mindlessly use it as a generic solution. Using `isset()` won't fix the problem. It will just sweep it under the rug, effectively acting as the *error suppression* operator, so when some your function will start returning incorrect value, you will never get a helpful error message that would have explained, why your program suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

The given warning:

```
Warning - Trying to access array offset on value of type null - PHP 7.4.0 #7776
```

results form this snippet `$key = $key[1];` and can be solved by using this instead:

```
$key = isset($key[1]) ? $key[1] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix for those that are not looking for the in depth detail, which I appreciated.  I was using an outdated setup instructions for XenForo

```
if ($_POST['t'] == 0) {
    /* get by id */
    $finder = \XF::finder('XF:User');
    $user = $finder->where('user_id', $_POST['v'])->fetchOne();
} else {
    /* get by name */
    $finder = \XF::finder('XF:User');
    $user = $finder->where('username', $_POST['v'])->fetchOne();
}
$columns = array("user_id", "username", "last_username");
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($columns); $i++) {
    $column = $columns[$i];
    $columns[$i] = array($column, $user[$column]);
}
```

so just add the `php !isset || !is_array`

```php
if (!isset($_POST['t']) || !is_array($_POST['t'])) {
    /* get by id */
    $finder = \XF::finder('XF:User');
    $user = $finder->where('user_id', $_POST['v'])->fetchOne();
} else {
    /* get by name */
    $finder = \XF::finder('XF:User');
    $user = $finder->where('username', $_POST['v'])->fetchOne();
}
$columns = array("user_id", "username", "last_username");
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($columns); $i++) {
    $column = $columns[$i];
    $columns[$i] = array($column, $user[$column]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Before accessing any element within the array, ensure the entire array itself is not null
> you can use if statement and isset() methood check like below

```
if(!isset($cOTLdata)){
//Handle the case where array is null
  return;
}
$list=$cOTLdata['char_data'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you are facing this issue in mpdf then**

1. go to Mpdf.php
2. search for this line:
   `$e = $this->otl->applyOTL($e, $this->CurrentFont['useOTL']);`
3. replace it with :`$e = preg_replace("/[\xe2\x80\x8c\xe2\x80\x8d\xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x80\x8f]/u", '', $e); $e = preg_replace("/[\xef\xbb\xbf]/u", '', $e);`

Comment: If possible, please use code blocks to make the answer more readable :)