# Cannot upload files with PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, file-upload, debian

I created a test folder on my Debian server because I can't handle uploading files to a directory. The browser shows me that I have uploaded the file, but when I look into the directory where the file should be uploaded, no file is shown. I have already set the folder to 777, but PHP does not upload anything.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

  <form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));
  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png", "mp3",
                     "acc", "wav", "3gpp", "mp4", "3gp", "m4a", "amr", "avi",
                    "flv", "gif");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152666655){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
    move_uploaded_file(
      $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
      $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'files/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]
    );
    header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}
?>
```

*files/* is set to 777 as already mentioned.

Comment: Are there any error logs/stack traces?

Comment: Nope there is no error or something like that. Only a success alert

Comment: Check the actual log files on the server.

Comment: What does `move_uploaded_file` return?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 

Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /var/www/html/test/upload.php on line 24, referer: ----

Comment: if you have errors, it should be in your `/var/log/` directory for `PHP`, `Nginx` or `Apache` think the error in your code the path for the destination, try this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/'`

Comment: Which line is 24?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336951/message-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 7.4 

Line is: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'files/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]

Its from 

move_uploaded_file(
      $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
      $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'files/' . $_FILES["image"]["name"]
    );