# Problem Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Tags: php

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

( **Notice**: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in....)

```
public function hasPermission($key)
{
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));
    if ($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->firstResult()->permissions, true);

        if ($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
if ($permissions[$key] == true) {
```

Regards

Comment: This question is already answered, example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336951/message-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null.

Comment: Are you sure the value for `$key` is available in the array?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do

```
if ($permissions[$key] == true) {
     return true;
}
```

Rather try this:

```
if (isset($permissions[$key]) && $permissions[$key]) {
    return true;
}
```

Hope this works!!

Answer (score -1):

It means that you're trying to get data from you're array while the parameter returns NULL in $permissions[$key]. So check if you're $key has any value.