# Error: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool - Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Since last PHP update an error have occured on our Wordpress homepage.

> "Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /htdocs/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-OLD/inc/helpers.php on line 2452.

```
        // Generate image URL if using ID
        if ( is_numeric( $bg_img ) ) {
            $bg_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img, 'full' );
            $bg_img = $bg_img[0]; //This is line 2452
        }

        $bg_img = $bg_img ? $bg_img : null;
        $bg_img = $bg_img;
```

Since I'm not really into that code overall, I've decided to ask for help from this forum.

Thanks in advance.

So far I havent tried anything by myself, I just don't want to break the code.

Comment: The error message is straightforward. You want to access an element in an Array, but the variable `$bg_img` is actually a boolean (true/ false). When you search for the fucntion name -> [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) you find the wordpress docs which explain, that when an image can't be found, a "false" is given back. So your task is to check for that, before you want to work with it.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: Here the accepted answer gives you an insight, why you get that message and did not get it before. [Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336951/message-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null)

Answer (score 0):

So your code should be like this:

```
// Generate image URL if using ID
   if ( is_numeric( $bg_img ) ) {
        $bg_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $bg_img, 'full' );
        if(is_array( $bg_img ) ){ //this condition will check that $bg_img is array or not
            $bg_img = $bg_img[0];
        }
    }
    $bg_img = $bg_img ? $bg_img : null;
    $bg_img = $bg_img;
```

Comment: Hi user5866, thanks for taking the time to answer. In your answer are some inaccuracies. You write - `..is numeric or not then $bg_img can't be array`. While the sentence is be true, it is not the error reason. A line later a function is called with the id in `$bg_img`, which gives back an Array or a Boolean. In this case the image can't be generated and `false` is assigned to `$bg_img`. More importantly __your second solution__ would pass the Array to the variable but not the expected value, so it is not okay, to "remove" the code, as it __breaks the code for all other working images__.

Comment: Sorry I missed that $bg_img is assigned again, Now i improve the code to check array