# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in php 8.1

Tags: php-8.1

I have updated PHP 7.3 to version 8.1 but with the following code, I get a warning:

```php
$this->m_intEventId = 
    $this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()[CEventSubType::WORKORDER_STATUS_UPDATED] 
        ?? $this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()[CEventSubType::WORKORDER_CLOSED] 
        ?? $this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()[CEventSubType::WORKORDER_CLOSED_AND_WORK_COMPLETED] 
        ?? $this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()[CEventSubType::WORKORDER_COMPLETED];
```

The warning is

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

We can use `isset()`, but in this case, do we need to check individual index with `isset()`? Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: My guess is, that one of the values returned by `$this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()` is `null`. If you then try to access the element at the given index, the warning is thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message: Trying to access array offset on value of type null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336951/message-trying-to-access-array-offset-on-value-of-type-null)

Comment: No doubt this is similar question but with different use case. My point it to addressed multiple conditions with isset. Is there way to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my guess is that one of the values returned by `$this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds()` is `null`. If you then try to access the element at the given index, the warning is thrown.

You have to check for `null` first using `isset()`. For example:

```php
function GetEventIdOfType($eventIds, $type) {
   if(isset($eventIds[$type])) {
      return $eventIds[$type];
   }

   return null;
}

$eventIds = $this->m_objMaintenanceRequest->getEventIds();

$this->m_intEventId = 
    GetEventIdOfType($eventIds, CEventSubType::WORKORDER_STATUS_UPDATED) 
        ?? GetEventIdOfType($eventIds, CEventSubType::WORKORDER_CLOSED)  
        ?? GetEventIdOfType($eventIds, CEventSubType::WORKORDER_CLOSED_AND_WORK_COMPLETED) 
        ?? GetEventIdOfType($eventIds, CEventSubType::WORKORDER_COMPLETED);
```

I did not test this code, but I think you get the idea. I also am assuming that only one of the array elements is set. If for example `CEventSubType::WORKORDER_STATUS_UPDATED` and `CEventSubType::WORKORDER_COMPLETED` are set, only the first is returned.